# How do you get a unique client ID on Citrix XenApp 6.0? (MFCom from 4.0 and 4.5 doesn't work)

Tags: client, unique, citrix, xenapp

Currently for Presentation Server 4.0 and 4.5, I am getting the unique client ID via MFCom in C# .NET.

```
MetaFrameFarm farm = new MetaFrameFarm();
farm.Initialize(MetaFrameObjectType.MetaFrameWinFarmObject);

foreach (MetaFrameSession session in farm.Sessions)
{
    clientId = session.ClientID;
.....
```

I began to get an error testing on 6.0. The line in question that is failing is the first line to instantiate a the object 'farm' above.

Looking online I found this...

> Starting in XenApp 6.0, MFCOM as a
>   publically supported programming and
>   scripting interface will no longer be
>   available. All existing MFCOM-based
>   code no longer works on XenApp 6.0. No
>   doubt that the absence of MFCOM will
>   be something that requires additional
>   effort to the adoption of XenApp 6.0.

Is there a way to get a unique client ID in 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty old, but I kept coming across this when I wanted to get a clientID.

Keep in mind the ClientIDs from 4.X don't appear to be the same format for 6.X. This goes for about all the IDs, App and Server:

```
Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
rs.Open();

PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = rs;

PSSnapInException ex;
rs.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Citrix.XenApp.Commands", out ex);

ps.AddCommand("GET-XASession").AddParameter("Full");

foreach (PSObject Session in ps.Invoke())
{
   try
   {
      ClientID = Convert.ToString(Session.Properties["ClientId"].Value);

      Console.WrileLine(ClientID);

   }

   catch (Exception e)
   {
      WriteError.WriteEntry("Client Failure " + e.Message + EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've correctly established, MFCOM is not available on XenApp 6. So, you're left with two ways of getting a unique ClientID:

1. **Use the Citrix WMI subsystem.** From within your application, connect to the Root\Citrix WMI namespace and enumerate instances of the MetaFrame_Session class. You can filter by server name (as the enumeration will return all sessions on *all* farm servers, not just the one you're running the application on) and session ID. The instances of the Metaframe_session class contain a couple of properties which are references to instances of other classes; the Client property references Metaframe_ICA_Client and the SessionUser property references Citrix_User. Metaframe_ICA_Client gives you the client's IP address, hostname and a few other things you could combine as an ID.
   However, currently XenApp 6 has a massive bug with the Citrix WMI subsystem and attempting to enumerate and instantiate the classes I've references above (as a normal user - admins are fine) results in no less than fifteen separate system services crashing... So maybe not.
2. The alternative (and the technique I employed) was to use the [Citrix WFAPI SDK](http://community.citrix.com/display/xa/WinFrame+API+SDK). It's unmanaged code and a bit of a pig, but there's a pretty good article on using WFAPI to grab client details [here](http://community.citrix.com/display/xa/How+to+get+Client+IP+and+hostname+using+Citrix+WFAPI+SDK).